# Indexing for query containing xml column

Tags: sql-server, performance, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below queries which performs little slow.So i am planning to create index.I created primay xml index and now performance improved little bit(by looking at execution plan) .Queries are shown below.

```
Update account set   [dailybalance].modify('replace value of   (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/Balance/text())[1] with   (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/ Balance)[1] +280')   where   [ID]=257 and [Date]='28-Feb-2013'  and  [dailybalance].exist('/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']')=1;

Update account  set   [dailybalance].modify('replace value of   (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/Transaction/text())[1] with   (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/ Transaction)[1] +280')   where   [ID]=257 and [Date]='28-Feb-2013'  and  [dailybalance].exist('/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']')=1;
```

The table has below structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[account ](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Type] [char](10) NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [Balance] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [TRansaction] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [mybal] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [dailybalance] [xml] NULL,
    [AutoIndex] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BalanceTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AutoIndex] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am using sql server 2008 r2 express.So i think i cannot use full text search. So please advice me how the index should be created so that above query performance is improved.

Comment: Improve performance by storing that information in relational tables instead of in XML.

Comment: Cant i do any indexing?

Answer (score 3):

If you are updating the xml that often, then consider property promotion, ie converting the xml to relational tables, as also suggested by others.

Re the design, are you storing Balance and Transaction in more than one place?  This sounds dangerous.  If the xml is a kind of history table then it might be better as that.  You could also make sure the history table is populated at the same time as the main table within a transaction so it's safe.  Your current design doesn't feel safe to me.  The fact your two UPDATEs above aren't done in a transaction is a bit worrying.  Have you had mismatches between the main table and xml?

Having said all that, I did a simple test rig to try and reproduce this problem and the UPDATEs run in under a second for me on my laptop on a 1 million row table.  Can you see anything different between this rig and your queries?

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[account]') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[account]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[account](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Type] [char](10) NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [Balance] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [TRansaction] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [mybal] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [dailybalance] [xml] NULL,
    [AutoIndex] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BalanceTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AutoIndex] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


-- Generate some dummy rows
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT TOP 1000000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS rn
FROM master.sys.columns c1
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c2
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c3
)
INSERT INTO dbo.account ( ID, [TYPE], [Date], Balance, [Transaction], mybal, dailybalance )
SELECT
      rn AS ID
    , CHAR( 65 + ( (rn -1) % 6 ) ) AS [TYPE]
    , DATEADD( day, (rn -1) % 90, '1 Jan 2013' ) AS [Date]
    , RAND() * 10 * ( (rn -1) % 10 ) AS [Balance]
    , RAND() * 10 * ( (rn -1) % 10 ) AS [Transaction]
    , RAND() * 10 * ( (rn -1) % 10 ) AS [mybal]

    , ( SELECT CONVERT( CHAR(10), DATEADD( month, x.y, '1 Jan 2013' ), 120 ) AS "date", x.y AS "Balance", 1 AS "Transaction" FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 12 column_id y FROM master.sys.columns ) x FOR XML PATH('Row'), ROOT('Root'), TYPE ) [dailybalance]

FROM cte
GO


-- Create data for our condition
UPDATE a
SET [Date] = '28-Feb-2013',
    dailybalance.modify('insert 
<Row>
  <date>2013-02-04</date>
  <Balance>-1</Balance>
  <Transaction>-1</Transaction>
</Row>

  as last into Root[1]
  ')
FROM dbo.account a
WHERE [ID] = 257
GO

-- Covering index for the query
-- CREATE INDEX _idx ON dbo.account ( ID, [Date] )


SELECT 'before' s, * FROM dbo.account
WHERE [ID] = 257


UPDATE account
SET [dailybalance].modify('replace value of (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/Balance/text())[1] 
with (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/Balance)[1] +280')   
WHERE [ID] = 257 
  AND [Date] = '28-Feb-2013'  
  AND [dailybalance].exist('/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']') = 1;


UPDATE account
set [dailybalance].modify('replace value of (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/Transaction/text())[1] 
with (/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']/Transaction)[1] +280')   
where [ID] = 257 
  and [Date] = '28-Feb-2013'  
  and  [dailybalance].exist('/Root/Row[date=''2013-02-04'']') = 1;


SELECT 'after' s, * FROM dbo.account
WHERE [ID] = 257
```

How many rows in your account table?  If your xml is actually very large, then that might explain things.  Could there be other issues such as blocking, triggers, or is the server busy?  Looking at the query, it's unlikely full-text indexing would help you much.  XML Indexing might help, but at a significant storage penalty.  The table can end up between 2-5 its original size and you don't have that much room to play with in SQL Express 2008 R2 (10GB), so again probably not recommended.

One other thing that *might* help is a covering index to support the UPDATE, eg

```
CREATE INDEX _idx ON dbo.account ( ID, [Date] )
```

Try that and see if that helps your UPDATE.  If not, try and provide the additional information requested above and I'll have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Full Text Indexing:  If you have SQL Server 2012 (or 2008 or 2008 R2) Express with Advanced Services (all free) then you will be able to create full text indexes in Express.  That download is currently available at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx

Having said that, I concur with the comments that using XML as a transport mechanism, but storing the data in relational tables is better for higher performing searches.  Basically you select from the XML using: VALUE('XQueryExpression','SQLType')

A sample from the SQL Server Books Online is:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
DECLARE @ProdID int
SET @myDoc = '<Root>
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">
<Features>
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>
</Features>
</ProductDescription>
</Root>'

SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )
SELECT @ProdID
```

If you want some sample code for shredding the XML into columns, see this post from **marc-s** that gives you a pattern to follow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179195/shredding-data-from-xml-importing-into-relational-tables-sql-server-2008

I use xml shredding to consume some event data in SQL Server, but not for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is not the most effective solution when it comes to XML parsing and manipulation.

you query performance should improve if you create an index on `ID ASC, [Date] ASC`. Depending on your other queries it might even make sense to create that index as clustered. In that case, if that column combination is not guaranteed to be unique include the `AutoIndex` column, also `ASC`.

If that is not enough you can try to add an XML index, however, that most likely won't help in your case (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx).

If you move the xml manipulation into a CLR procedure you might also gain some performance, as the SQL Server implementation is - as I said before - not the fastest.

The biggest performance gain you would get by storing the data in relational tables instead of XML.